# API Platform: MaxDepth by request parameter

Tags: api-platform.com

I'm new to API Platform and I'm creating some relations in my API, but I want to limit maximal depth of output (for example menu has submenu, which has submenu, etc. - I want to limit this depth).

Is there any way to set max depth by a GET parameter (or some other parameter in a request)?